# user-data is not getting executed on custom AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to execute user-data on a custom ubuntu image (AMI) created after deploying some software. however user data not get executed.

Moreover, if I try to execute same user-data on a community ubuntu AMI it gets executed successfully.

What Modification I need to do in my custom ubuntu AMI so that it can execute User-data.

I tired deleting the content of /var/lib/cloud/ folder and created AMI again however still user-data did not got executed.

Kindly advice !!!

Comment: Is [CloudInit](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CloudInit) installed? By default, it only runs once per Instance ID -- effectively, the first time the instance is booted. New instances launched from the AMI will have a different Instance ID, so they will execute on the first boot.

Comment: apparently i got it resolved !!! looks it was some configuration issue where instance was not able to communicate outside the vpc